# Qt and OpenCV static libraries conflict with each other

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, opencv, static-libraries

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, OpenCV 2.4.5, and QT 5.0.2.
I'm trying to deploy my application by loading static libraries of OpenCV and QT.
The problem is that both of them contain **zlib** (compression library) internally.
So, when I compile the project, link error occurs, since symbols are conflicted as below.

```
zlibd.lib(zutil.obj) : error LNK2005: _z_errmsg is already defined in Qt5Cored.lib(zutil.obj).
```

However, both of OpenCV and QT do not provide static library without zlib.
What can I do?

Comment: My advice is to build OpenCV yourself with the same compiler that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [OpenCV installation guide](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide). It says, "You can use Qt as HighGUI backend on any platforms (Windows, Linux, Mac) by passing `WITH_QT=ON` to CMake when configuring OpenCV." The guide also has a link to a step-by-step guide.

So, do these [steps](http://code.google.com/p/qt-opencv-multithreaded/wiki/Documentation) and add `WITH_QT=ON` to your OpenCV configuration.